# Can't upload a .sppkg add-in to the Office Store

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-store

I am trying to put an add-in on the Office Store, under the SharePoint Add-Ins section. It's a simple SPFx webpart.

The file is a .sppkg (SPFx package), but the store is demanding that my add-in should have the extension .app.

I'm a bit stuck - is there any way to share a .sppkg add-in? Presumably you can't just change the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to distribute SharePoint Framework packages are by somehow get them into the hands of the tenant administrator and let them add them to the Application Catalog. They can't be added to the Store and I hope that this will not change as there is no way to secure them.

In [this blog post](https://dev.office.com/blogs/sharepoint-framework-developer-preview-release) from the SharePoint team you can see that they still promote Add-ins for Office store distibution (end of third last paragraph).

Comment: Thanks Per - I think you can still add [SharePoint add-ins](https://store.office.com/en-us/appshome.aspx?productgroup=sharepoint&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) (but I guess not SharePoint Framework packages).  I wonder if there is some way to convert the sppkg into something modern enough to be accepted.

Comment: Yes add-ins was created very much with 3rd party developers in mind, that the reason for all the IFrame stuff to handle security. That's not the case with SPFx

Comment: @PerJakobsen still in 2018 also it is same? We cannot add spfx pkg to sharepoint store?

Comment: Is this the same in May-2022? I'm not able to upload the sppkg file to Office store.